# How to link Node, Edge, and Dijkstra class to Main method properly

Tags: java, class, variables, methods

I am using variables and methods in my main method that are from my `Dijkstra`, `Edge` and `Node` class. I am getting errors within the main method saying that the methods are undefined for the type main and the variables cannot be resolved either.

I have tried `Dijkstra obj = new Dijkstra();` in my `main` method, but it didn't change a thing. If I could figure that one out first the other two will come to me as well.

````
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args){     
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(new 
     File("C:/Users/China/Desktop/al1.txt"));

                String line = sc.nextLine();
                String[] ne = line.split(" ");            

                nodes = Integer.parseInt(ne[0].split("=")[1]);
                edges = Integer.parseInt(ne[1].split("=")[1]);

                Dijkstra obj = new Dijkstra();

                constructGraphFlow(sc);
                ```

    public class Dijkstra {
           ```
           public static void constructGraphFlow(Scanner sc){
           ```
           } ```
````

I just need to get that method working

Comment: From the code that you posted, it appears that `nodes` in method `main()` is a variable. Where is this variable declared? I don't see its declaration in the code you posted.

Comment: @Abra the variable declarations are also within the Dijkstra class. I left it out to try to keep things short and sweet. I was hoping that by getting the method to work the variables would also link in the process.

Comment: Speaking only for myself, I need to see all your code in order to help you. But as far as I am aware, you cannot access variables in class `Dijkstra` from class `Main` with the code that you posted. Hence the error messages you claim to be getting. By the way, posting the entire error will probably also help me. And if you are getting a stack trace, it wouldn't hurt to post that too.